# Order State in Magento2

Tags: magento2, order-status

I am getting all status which I have created from admin by the following code in my configuration section now I want to show just `complete` and `processing` state status

```
foreach($this->salesOrderConfigFactory->create()->getStatuses() as $status => $statusLabel) 
{
    $returnArray[] = array('value' => $status, 'label' => __($statusLabel));
}
return $returnArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code :

```
foreach($this->salesOrderConfigFactory->create()->getStatuses() as $status => $statusLabel) 
{
    if($status == "complete" || $status == "processing"){
      $returnArray[] = array('value' => $status, 'label' => __($statusLabel));
    }
}
return $returnArray;
```

Comment: its showing one status i have 3 status on processing state